# MAC filtering, How to auto log in to a webpage?

Tags: security, mac-address, captive-portal

My building provides internet access. But before you can use it, you need to browse to a website. From there you are redirected to the building's router which asks you for a user name and password, after that it allows one MAC on the network (coffee shop/airport style MAC filtering). This setup is a pain.

What I'm trying to do is set up an ubuntu based box, that will function as a NAT and bridge my own network with my three computers and my phone onto the buildings network using a single MAC address.

The bit I'm stuck on is how to get my NAT box to log in completely autonomously.
This has stumped a few people. Any ideas?

Comment: Note: this is called [Captive portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do something like this:

1. Install HTTPFox (or other Firefox addon) to view what exactly is sent to the portal to authenticate;
2. Construct "curl" (command-line HTTP client) command that does the same
3. Schedule that curl command to be executed periodically or when connection requires authentication.